# What's the right layer for a socket connection?

Tags: architecture, n-tier-architecture

I guess there is no right anwser to this question- If I have a module thats responsible for connection and data transportation with the server(using a simple socket connection, not a web service case) is it right to put that module under my data access layer assembly or should I create another layer(service layer) for that job?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on your design. Where do you feel like it should fit in? What layers is it going to interact with?

Comment: It sounds like you're leaning towards separation, and while that's better for modularity, Damien Black is absolutely right.  If the only use for the network is to connect to your data access, there's not much utility in walling them off except formality.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing data, you want that to go in a layer...  Data Access Layer is pretty cut and dry.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:
[Chapter 8: Data Layer Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658127.aspx)

Notice the 'Service Agent' part of the Data Layer in the Figure 1 and it's appropriate description.
To put it short: DAL is the place that you want to give all the data to your business layer and DAL should know how to get that data.

Of course, you'll most probably want to abstract DAL in some way (repository?) because if tomorrow your socket-connection based data source service adds web service support, you'll maybe want to be able to easily support that also. In that case, you would just change implementation of Service Agent in your DAL without touching anything in Business layer nor Repository.